# How do i make a toggle save its state between React Routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to build a dark mode toggle in JS using React.
I'm using Material-UI to design my page and I've managed to make the button change the theme of my whole page when clicked. My issue is that whenever I refresh or change the Routes, the button state doesn't get carried over. Is there anything I'm missing?

This is the code for my button:

```
export default function ThemeSwitch({ toggleDark, settoggleDark }) {
  const handleModeChange = () => {
    settoggleDark(!toggleDark);
  };
  return (
    <div className="theme-btn">
      <IOSSwitch
        checked={toggleDark}
        onChange={handleModeChange}
        name="toggleDark"
        color="default"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

And this is my App.js:

```
function App() {
  const [toggleDark, settoggleDark] = useState(false);

  const myTheme = createTheme({
    palette: {
      mode: toggleDark ? "dark" : "light",
      primary: {
        main: "#ff1744",
      },
      secondary: {
        main: "#880e4f",
      },
    },
  });

  return (
    <Router>
      <ThemeProvider theme={myTheme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <Navbar />
        <ThemeSwitch
          toggleDark={toggleDark}
          settoggleDark={settoggleDark}
          className="theme-btn"
        />
        <UserAuthContextProvider>
          <Routes>
            <Route
              path="/"
              element={
                <ProtectedRoute>
                  <Hero />
                </ProtectedRoute>
              }
            />
            <Route path="signup" element={<SignUp />} />
            <Route path="signin" element={<SignIn />} />
          </Routes>
        </UserAuthContextProvider>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to maintain the value, you can use localStorage instead of react state.

Whenever you set the state save it in local storge like:

```
localStorage.setItem("toggleDark", true);
```

And get the state by using

```
localStorage.getItem("toggleDark");
```

Comment: I've managed to do that, but the button won't dynamically update the theme whenever I click it. It only performs the change on a refresh

Comment: make this change  useEffect(()=>{
    location.setItem("toggleDark",toggleDark)
  },[toggleDark])

Comment: and add this                     let mode = true;
  try {
      mode = localStorage.getItem("toogleDark");
  } catch (error) {}

  const theme = createTheme({
      palette: {
          mode: mode === "false" ? "dark" : "light",
      },
  });

Comment: I think I pulled it off like this:
In my App.js I've only changed:
` 
const [toggleDark, settoggleDark] = useState(
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("toggleDark"))
  );
`
And my handleModeChange now looks like this:
`  const handleModeChange = () => {
    localStorage.setItem(
      "toggleDark",
      !JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("toggleDark"))
    );
    settoggleDark(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("toggleDark")));
  };
`